# Is there a way to use a using-declaration inside a requires-expression

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-concepts, requires-expression

I want to test whether a type can be passed to some function, but I'd like to use ADL on the function lookup and include a function from a certain namespace.

Consider this code:

```cpp
#include <utility>
#include <vector>

template<class T>
concept Swappable = requires(T& a, T& b)
{
    swap(a,b);
};

static_assert(Swappable<std::vector<int>>); // #1
static_assert(Swappable<int>); // #2
```

#1 succeeds, it finds `std::swap` because `std` is an associated namespace of `std::vector<int>`. But #2 fails, a built-in type has no associated namespace.

How would I write something like:

```cpp
template<class T>
concept Swappable = requires(T& a, T& b)
{
    using std::swap; // illegal
    swap(a,b);
};
```

AFAIK, you're not allowed to use a using-declaration inside a requires-expression.

**(NOTE** Although there is a perfectly fine standard C++ concept for this, `std::swappable`, this example uses `swap` for exposition only. I'm not particularly looking to test whether something is actually swappable, I'm just trying to find a way to implement such a concept where a customization function has a default implementation in a known namespace, but might have overloads in an associated namespace.**)**

**EDIT** As a workaround, I can implement the concept in a separate namespace where the names are pulled in. Not too happy about it but it works.

```cpp
namespace detail
{
    using std::swap;

    template<class T>
    concept Swappable = requires(T& a, T& b)
    {
        swap(a,b);
    };
}

// and then either use it
using detail::Swappable;

// or redefine it
template<class T>
concept Swappable = detail::Swappable<T>;
```

Comment: Is this actually a helpful concept? If you constrain a template parameter on `Swappable`, you still have to `using std::swap` to be safe

Comment: But in my particular case, I want the code to behave a certain way if a certain set of functions are defined for it, and in another way if it doesn't. So I want to have a concept to be able to test for it.

Comment: @oisyn: "*I want the code to behave a certain way if a certain set of functions are defined for it, and in another way if it doesn't.*" Then you're going to have to explain what that behavior is, and why you need it to have that behavior. If the example you give is over-simplified, then we're going to give you overly-simplistic answers.

Comment: My question is simple. How do I use using declarations inside a requires expression. I'm asking from a language perspective, I don't care about a potential xy-problem.

Comment: @oisyn: "*I'm asking from a language perspective, I don't care about a potential xy-problem.*" Concepts don't let you do this precisely because you *shouldn't do this*. That is, during the design of the feature, the idea probably came up, and they said, "we shouldn't be doing that to begin with; there are better ways to solve that problem." Whether you personally care about the XY issue, the language (and your users) definitely does care.

Comment: Just to clarify in case of `std::vector` [Argument Dependent Lookup](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/adl) (ADL) kicks in. You should just use `std::vetor(a, b)`;

Comment: @oisyn: And note that *users* of this concept will not appreciate having to shove `using` declarations everywhere either. The language is not meant for you to be able to do this, and your interface should accept that.

Comment: Can you explain why you didn't consider to use `std::vetor(a, b);`?

Comment: @NicolBolas Users won't use this concept. I just need it to implement behavior for some generic types. I'm writing a serialization library where users call a function for the members of the struct they want serialized. They only need to customize this function for their types, but I want to have standard implementations for container-like and tuple-like types. Rather than having to write an overload for each container type, I'd like to test whether it supports an iterable range using `begin(c)`/`end(c)`, similar for `get<N>(t)` for tuples. Unfortunately, this not only applies to `std`.

Comment: @MarekR Not sure what you mean by "use `std::vetor(a,b)`" (I'm assuming you mean `vector` here instead of `vetor`, but that doesn't make it clearer).

Comment: Sidenote, there is [`std::swappable`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concepts/swappable)

Comment: @oisyn just thinking about one thing and typing other. It suppose to be `std::swap(a, b);` :).

Comment: @MarekR You're not allowed to overload functions in `std`, so if you want to implement `swap()` for your own type, you'll need to do that outside of `std`. As a result, any generic code directly calling `std::swap()` bypasses your specialized implementation. That's why it's recommended to do the `using std::swap; swap(a, b);` idiom in generic code, because that way it finds the `std` implementation as well as any other associated namespace of `a` and `b`.

Of course, `std::ranges::swap()` takes care of this boilerplate for you, as @NicolBolas explained, so that would be the preferred way.

Comment: why someone like to overload `std::swap`?

Comment: Not `std::swap` but `swap`. That's why you want to call `swap` instead of `std::swap`.

Comment: EOT for me since apparently we are not on the same page.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can put it inside a lambda:

```cpp
template<class T>
concept Swappable = []{
    using std::swap;
    return requires(T& a, T& b) { swap(a, b); };
}();
```

Comment: Nice, cool trick! I experimented with lambda's to solve my issue, but the requires-expression doesn't check their bodies, any errors in there are just hard compiler errors. But I hadn't considered returning a requires expression from a lambda!

Answer (score 5):

Avoid using old `using`-based idioms. Instead, use the customization point equivalents like `ranges::swap`.

That is, you should not require users to use `using`-based idioms in their code. Provide a customization point object that does what it needs to. The `operator()` overloads/templates can be constrained to create the effect of the `using` idiom without requiring the user to actually invoke `using`.

[`ranges::swap` is a good example of how this gets done.](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/ranges/swap)

Comment: Some people need to deal with the mountains of existing code that uses `using`-base idioms though...

Comment: Yes that's mainly my issue here as well. Also, I think the language customization points are better from a user-perspective, but *I* don't yet fully understand them, let alone that I can expect my team to maintain them. It's just terrible C++ code from a readibility standpoint.

Comment: @oisyn: "*It's just terrible C++ code from a readibility standpoint.*" And throwing a bunch of `using` directives everywhere *isn't*? `ranges::swap(...)` is way more readable than `using std::swap; swap(...)`. And even better, it can be used in places where you can't have `using` directives. Like... concepts ;)

Comment: For `swap` - probably yes, but to write your own `std::ranges::swap`-like object, you'll need a way to use `using` in a concept anyway.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat: Not really. The reason you need `using std::swap` is for types where the `swap` function is defined in the `std` namespace but cannot otherwise be accessed. But these are *only* for fundamental types; all user-defined types are supposed to rely on ADL for swapping. So `ranges::swap::operator()` simply uses concepts to check if the type is a fundamental type and does the swapping itself.

Comment: @NicolBolas Now *this* is an interesting point you raise here. I can work around it in a similar way for built-in types.

Comment: @NicolBolas Objects of class type can be swappable without finding `swap` via ADL, using the "default" behaviour of `std::swap` and move constructing/assigning, so checking for fundamental types isn't enough. Example: https://godbolt.org/z/j9MYGr43r

Comment: @Artyer: I didn't say that was the entirety of the algorithm. Obviously, it also needs to check for member `swap`, and then to check if the types are moveable/constructable, etc. The point being that you can do all of the stuff that `using std::swap` does without actually doing that.

Answer (score -2):

Interesting, the below code works well again:

```
#include <concepts>

    template <typename T, typename U = T>
    concept Swappable = requires(T&& a, U&& b) {
        std::swap(a, b);
    };
    
    int main() {
        static_assert(Swappable<int>); 
        static_assert(Swappable<int, int>);
        return 0;
    }
```

I see an example from cppconference, but I could not get expected results. [Cpp reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/requires).  [See code here](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/T5sbv694h):

```
template <typename T, typename U = T>
concept Swappable = requires(T&& a, U&& b) {
    swap(std::forward<T>(a), std::forward<U>(b));
    swap(std::forward<U>(b), std::forward<T>(a));
};

int main() {
    static_assert(!Swappable<int>); // Wrong, int is definately swappable!
    static_assert(!Swappable<int, int>); // Wrong, int is definately swappable!
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @Adriaan I updated and provide one runnable answer here. and I think we could discuss this swap concept here, you see the cppreference code actually provides one answer and I attach it to here.

Comment: Your example works because it just uses `swap` from the `std` namespace, but a 3rd party type implementing `swap` implements it in its own namespace (as you're not allowed to overload `std::swap`). So you need to use ADL by doing `swap(...)` rather than `std::swap(...)`. But then `std::swap` needs to be visible from that scope. This whas the whole point of my question; how do we do that in a requires clause. Your answer doesn't answer it.